# Apache: How to serve a path from a different directory without symlinking?

Tags: apache

I have a one project being hosted in Apache under a specific subdomain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.example.com
    DocumentRoot /web/vhosts/dev.example.com
    <Directory />
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to serve another project under a subdirectory of this domain:

```
dev.example.com/special-project
```

Which lives in `/web/vhosts/special-project`. I also can't simply create a symlink to this directory because of the way the original project is structured. It has to be configured using Apache only.

How do I configure Apache to be able to do this? Also, can this type of configuration be specified in a separate file, or does it have to be part of the original `VirtualHost` definition?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use an [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias).

```
Alias /special-project/ /web/vhosts/special-project/
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to work. All the files in this directory are static, so if I wanted http://dev.example.com/special-project to point to an index.html file in that directory...what would I need to do?

Comment: Ahh...nevermind...I did not add the trailing slash to the directory path. Apparently, that is required. I also removed the trailing slash on the subdirectory path and it makes the trailing slash in the URL optional.

Comment: DONT FORGET TRAILING SLASH!

Answer (score -3):

Just add another virtual host like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName special-project.example.com
    DocumentRoot /web/vhosts/special-project
    <Directory />
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: wouldn't adding this as a subdomain require updating some DNS records? I'm trying to avoid this by making it a subdirectory (not a subdomain)

Comment: Then @unbeli 's solution is what you are looking for :)